# Ubuntu 20.04 Palemoon takes 26 seconds to open

Tags: 20.04, palemoon

Ubuntu 20.04 fresh install, but Palemoon takes 26 seconds to start! Have removed and re-installed, but still 26 seconds. Other than move to a different OS is there anything I can do to get back to the 18.04 speedy start for Palemoon?

Comment: having a SSD instead of just a hard disc is a game changer ...  also in today's world as a developer you need 16 gigs of RAM or just 8 gigs as someone who just using the browser a lot ...  if its trying to launch by showing tons of tabs saved from previous launch  it will help to zap all but a few tabs ...  dunno about palemoon however some browsers have a setting to lazy load tabs on launch which speeds up the browser launch ... slowness is due to running low on either RAM, CPU or network ...  hit the META key ( possibly labeled WIN ) then type in  system ... click on `System Monitor`

Comment: now after `System Monitor` is running then launch that browser so you can identify which resource is running low  ( CPU ,  RAM ,  network )

Comment: Can you edit your question to include specs? Is it only Palemoon that is slow to start? Does starting with extensions/add-ons disabled and/or a new empty session with a single tab help?

Comment: Have I3 7320, SSD 250GB plus 16GB RAM. Palemoon always starts with just home tab open, there are no extensions or add-ons. I will run the test suggested and report later, but I have to go and work now. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: System Monitor showed that CPU usage never exceeded 40% for any core whilst I waited the 26 seconds for Pale moon to open. Memory  and Swap remained at ~10% throughout.

Comment: It is only Pale moon that has seen any change to opening speed since upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. Can not recall having any slowness issue in the past 10+ years as a Ubuntu user on 4 to 6 pc's of various specs. Network did not exceed ~500 bytes/s, that was the peak when I asked for Pale moon. Generally only use one application (program) at a time.